# How to modify a DataTable's Query Generated in the designer with code

Tags: dataset, rdlc

I have a RDLC file with a dataset Created in the designer and the report loads ok no errors.
My problem is the query in the DataTable is alway's the same.
I would like to change that query in the designer but haveb't been able.
I also have tried to create the dataset in code and then add it yo the RDLC file but I was not successful to add the Dataset to the RDLC.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you want to load a custom DataTable inside your report:

```
//clean old dataset
yourReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
DataTable yourDataTable = null;

yourDataTable = loadDataTableFromYourDataSource();

ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("YourDataSourceNameFoundInsideTheRdlc", yourDataTable);
yourReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);

//refresh the report
yourReport.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

hope it helps